# Custom menu named arguments

Tags: 7, routes

i was wondering is it possible to create custom menu named arguments in D7. I can do this

```
function MY_MODULE_menu(){
  $items['my/callback/%user'] = array(
    ...
    'page callback' => 'MY_MODULE_callback',
    'page arguments' => array(2),
    ....
  );
}
```

and it will load the user entity. So instead i want to do this:

```
function MY_MODULE_menu(){
  $items['my/callback/%my_entity'] = array(
    ...
    'page callback' => 'MY_MODULE_callback',
    'page arguments' => array(2),
    ....
  );
}
```

and my custom entity to be loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, name your function **my_entity_load** and it will be passed the id.

From the Drupal [hook_menu documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) (emphasis mine).

> Auto-Loader Wildcards Registered paths may also contain special
>   "auto-loader" wildcard components in the form of '%mymodule_abc',
>   where the '%' part means that this path component is a wildcard, and
>   the 'mymodule_abc' part defines the prefix for a load function, which
>   here would be named mymodule_abc_load(). When a matching path is
>   requested, your load function will receive as its first argument the
>   path component in the position of the wildcard; load functions may
>   also be passed additional arguments (see "load arguments" in the
>   return value section below). **For example, your module could register
>   path 'my-module/%mymodule_abc/edit':**
>
> ```
>   $items['my-module/%mymodule_abc/edit'] = array(
>     'page callback' => 'mymodule_abc_edit',
>     'page arguments' => array(1),
>   );
> ```
>
> **When path 'my-module/123/edit' is requested, your load function
>   mymodule_abc_load() will be invoked with the argument '123', and
>   should load and return an "abc" object with internal id 123:**
>
> ```
>   function mymodule_abc_load($abc_id) {
>     return db_query("SELECT * FROM {mymodule_abc} WHERE abc_id = :abc_id", array(':abc_id' => $abc_id))->fetchObject();
>   }
> ```

Comment: I have no idea how i missed that, the answer was RTFM :) Thanks Thomas for the help and pointing the solution out.